# Javascript to handle a form return

Tags: asp.net, forms

I have a standard html registration page that targets an external .asp page on submit.
What happens is that currently the .asp (which I don't have access to)returns an entire html page.
Instead I would like to somehow parse the returned html and populate the existing form with either
a) validation errors if incorrect
or
B) some sort of success message if all validated

Can anyone tell me if this is possible and or help with some pseudo code?

Comment: What's that have to do with asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is doable in JavaScript using ajax, but it requires that the ASP page (presumably on a different domain) sends appropriate CORS HTTP headers.  Even if you don't have access to the actual ASP page, you may be able to get someone to setup the headers in IIS on their server.

Otherwise, you're stuck moving everything server-side, i.e. simulating the POST on your own webserver, and scraping the HTML to get the status back.  That looks something like:

1. Postback the page to your own page (or use Ajax)
2. On your server, initiate a web request post of the data to the ASP page
3. Parse the results in your server code
4. Return an appropriate response to the browser client

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do, assuming I'm interpreting your question correctly, is "scrape" the HTML returned from the asp page and make proper assumptions about the location and meaning of the text within the markup. I, personally, would strongly advise against developing anything of any kind of robustness based on what amounts to screen scraping, especially considering you don't have access to the .asp file itself. If I've misunderstood your problem, my apologies.